# I have two entities and two repositories. How save data in entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Entity named as `Country` and `Region`.

Repository named as `CountryRepository` and `RegionRepository`.

How to store data in `Region` entity?

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

$countryId=$em->getRepository('LocationBundle:Country')->find(1));
$region=new Region(); //How to create Region Ojbect
$region->setCountryId($countryId);
$region->setName('abc');
$region->save();
```

Comment: here's the doc, better when read... http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should modify the  first line of you Controller Action with something like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

Secondly, you have to implement a constructor of Region in its Entity, and in Controller you have to pass properly parameters of constructor.

Finally, to save the new Region into database, yo have to use the following statements:

```
    $em->persist($region); 
    $em->flush();
```